# asp.net mvc using string id on details view

Tags: asp.net

Please help me to find error on my code

public ActionResult Details(string id)
{
String connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SAPB1"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
String sql = "Select a.[CardCode] As CCODE,a.[CardName] As Name from ocrd a where a.CardCode = " + id;
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

```
        BPModel BP = new BPModel();
        using (conn)
        {
            conn.Open();
            
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
            {
                

            }

            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                BP.CCODE = rdr["CCODE"].ToString();
                BP.Name = rdr["Name"].ToString();

            }




        }

        return View(BP);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap your `id` values inside single quote ('). Try like below.

```
String sql = "Select a.[CardCode] As CCODE,a.[CardName] As Name from ocrd a where a.CardCode = '" + id + "'";
```